# Integration Rule Exact Degree

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, interpolation

Given the integration rule $Q(x) = \alpha_1f(0)+\alpha_2f(1)+\alpha_3f'(0)$ for interpolating the integral $\int_0^1f(x) dx$ , I need to find $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$ values s.t Q has exact degree of n=2.

For exact degree of n=2 , I know that we must have :
$\int_0^1 1 = 1,\int_0^1 x = 0.5,\int_0^1 x^2 = 1/3$ , 
but I cannot find out how to find $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$ that answer these constraints.

I'd be grateful if anyone could point me to the solution,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any function $f$, let
$$I(f) = \int^{1}_{0} f(x) \, dx$$
provided the integral exists. Let
$$Q(f) = \alpha_1f(0) + \alpha_2f(1) + \alpha_3f'(0)$$
be a quadrature that approximates $I(f)$. The error in the approximation is given by
$$E(f) = I(f) - Q(f).$$
If the quadrature has degree of precision $2$, then $E(1) = E(x) = E(x^2) = 0$.

$$E(1) = \int^{1}_{0} dx - (\alpha_1 + \alpha_2) = 1 - \alpha_1 - \alpha_2 = 0.$$
$$E(x) = \int^{1}_{0} x \, dx - (\alpha_2 + \alpha_3) = \frac{1}{2} - \alpha_2 - \alpha_3 = 0.$$
$$E(x^2) = \int^{1}_{0} x^2 \, dx - \alpha_2 = \frac{1}{3} - \alpha_2 = 0.$$
The solution to this linear system is
$$\alpha_1 = \frac{2}{3}, \quad \alpha_2 = \frac{1}{3}, \quad \alpha_3 = \frac{1}{6}.$$

Comment: Ben ,first of all thanks for the answer. I'd like to know why for example in the calculation of $E(1)$ we get $f(0)=1,f(1)=1,f'(0)=0$ . Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that $Q(1) = \alpha_1(1) + \alpha_2(1) + \alpha_3(0)$, since $f(x) = 1$ for all $x$ so $f'(x) = 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Thanks again,but why $f(x)=1$ for all x ?

Comment: Because we are considering $E(f)$ where $f(x) = 1$ for all $x$, which we write as $E(1)$